# Third version of ISO9660

Tags: dvd, ubuntu-mate, burning

I am trying to burn some files to a DVD.

When I did so, I got this message,

[image]

Do I need to install the 3rd version of ISO9660?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

**[ISO9660](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_9660)** is a type of file system used for optical discs.

This file system has roots that go back several decades.  In that time, the standards for ISO9660 have undergone several revisions.  These are also referred sometimes as versions, standards, or levels.

**Your burning software already knows how to write different versions of the ISO9660 standard.  You are not being prompted to install anything.**

**This notification is warning you of two things:**

1. ***If you intend to burn a disk containing any single file larger than 2GiB, the disc will be burned using the third version of ISO9660*** (because earlier versions of the ISO9660 standard can't support files that large)
2. ***The third version of ISO9660 is not compatible with all operating systems.***  This means that a disc written using this standard might not be readable on another computer. The notification informs you that a disc written using this standard will be readable on Linux and all versions of Windows, but the disc will not be readable on MacOS X.

**By clicking "Never Add Such File"**, you acknowledge the notification and instruct your burning software to never add a file larger than 2GiB. All discs will be written with an earlier ISO9660 standard that has no compatibility issues (even w/ MacOS X).

**By clicking "Always Add Such File"**, you acknowledge the notification and instruct the software to proceed even when you add files larger than 2GiB.  If you do add files larger than 2GiB, the disc might not be readable on another operating system.

Comment: So, is does the warning only apply to those who are using Windows also? @Nmath

Comment: It "*is supported by most operating systems, including Linux and all versions of Windows*" - copied straight from the warning :)

Comment: I think you missed my point. Why would the warning say to use the 3rd version? I assume that it thinks I do not have the 3rd version.

Comment: @fixit7 I have added detail to the answer.  I hope this helps